# Writing string to a file in php via web

Tags: php

Hi i need help writing data to a file in php via web, for example i use http://1.1.1.1/file.php?&file=lol.txt and it doesn't write but when i take out $_GET and just put a random file name and run through the terminal it works, any ideas on why it wont work via web?

I've tried switching to file_put_contents() but it did the same thing, didn't work via web but worked in terminal.

my code below

```php
<?php
    $file = $_GET['file'];
    $file_name = "/var/www/html/$file";
    $myfile = fopen($file_name, "a+") or $myfile = fopen($file_name, "r");
    chmod($file_name, 0777);
    $text = "hello there\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $text);
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

it doesn't show any error messages i just wanted to know if i was missing anything or?

Comment: Mind sharing the error message? And please keep in mind that using unfiltered user input like you do here is an ultra high security risk. If you plan to put this on the internet I'd highly suggest that you read up on processing user input.

Comment: It didn't give any error messages on the terminal it worked and ran fine, but when i tried to use it via web it loaded fine as if it worked but there was no data written to the file, also i'm just using this for a localhost project haha but appreciate the concern and help

Comment: yeah agree. code looks good but I think it is better to rewrite with POST.

Comment: Are you serving it with Apache? I just served it with the PHP builtin webserver (`php -S`) and it worked fine. Could you check if it is possible to write the file inside the current directory, i. e. `$file_name = $file`.

Comment: Ok, i tried writing inside of current directory and its doing same thing, and yes i'm using Apache on centos 6

Comment: Is there anyway you could show me some code that would work?, i can use a string inside the file to define filename i don't need to use GET to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Change folder premissions:

```
// Folder owner: apache (Centos) or www-data (Debian)
// owner:group 
chown -R apache:yourusername /var/www/html
// Folder permissions 775 or 777 for all
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html
```

Btw. secure file name first and test file extension:

```
$file_name = "/var/www/html/".basename($file);
```